# debug gdb and ROS

Tags: ros, gdb, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to debug my rosnode with gdb because I am getting a segmentation fault. My package name is `renv` and the executable inside it is names `env`

I can run `rosrun renv env --env 1` and it works. When I do `rosrun renv env --env 2` it gives me a SegFault.

I tried:

`gdb --args rosrun renv env --env 2` and gdb says rosrun is not executable (makes sense as it's a shell script)

`gdb --args renv env --env 2` and gdb says renv not found

`gdb --args env --env 2` and gdb gets confused and trued running /usr/bin/env

I have enabled debugging symbols in CMake using

```
if(MSVC)  
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Zi")  
else()  
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")  
endif()
```

And I find a lot of answers pointing to [Roslaunch nodes and gdb + valgrind](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) ... and It's difficult for me to understand that ... I think it says to use `gdb --args` for the gdb part - But I don't know what to put after that :P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211226/debug-gdb-and-ros/) by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `--prefix` option to rosrun:

```
rosrun --prefix 'gdb --args' renv env --env 2
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) on 2015-06-13**:
This makes complete sense but I never knew the `--prefix` option existed. Thanks !

**Comment by [physincubus](https://answers.ros.org/users/25664/physincubus/) on 2016-02-05**:
supremely helpful